# How to trigger Vue event when selecting an option from select list

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qc7yqvvs/

It works when I use the mouse to click on an option, but if I use the arrow keys to navigate the options it won't update the `multiplier`. The guide only has the `:click` event, I tried with `:select`, `:enter` and others but they don't seem to exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event you are probably after is `v-on:change` or shorthand: `@change`. You'd then set this on the `select` rather than the options.

However you'll probably find it easier to do this by changing the multiplier to an object and then using the intervals value to select the corresponding one, i.e.

**EDIT**

Following your comments I see it may be tricky to build objects within the component so you'd rather set them in the html. To do so try binding the value of each option and then setting an object instead on the v-model, i.e.

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
    data: function() {
        return {
            value: {},
        }
    },
    computed: {
        total: function() {
            return this.value.interval ? (this.value.interval * this.value.multiplier).toFixed(2) : 0
        }
    }
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <my-component inline-template>
        <div>
            <select size="6" v-model="value">
                <option :value="{ interval: 24, multiplier: 1 }">24</option>
                <option :value="{ interval: 12, multiplier: 0.71 }">12</option>
                <option :value="{ interval: 8, multiplier: 0.56 }">8</option>
                <option :value="{ interval: 4, multiplier: 0.47 }">4</option>
                <option :value="{ interval: 2, multiplier: 0.25 }">2</option>
                <option :value="{ interval: 1, multiplier: 0.12 }">1</option>
            </select>
            <p>
                value: {{ value }}
            </p>
            <p>
                Total: {{ total }}
            </p>
        </div>
    </my-component>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting the intervals and corresponding multipliers from the database using Laravel. How do I go about creating that object with my current setup?

Comment: thats quite a different question so perhaps if this answer your initial one you can mark it so. However I assume you have the interval & corresponding multiplier values? If so can you not just build an object from them and set this to the value of `this.multiplier` when ready?

Comment: Updated answer assuming you need to set all values within the html

Comment: That answers my question. But how do I handle the form submission now? The value of the field is all weird (`value="[object Object]"`). How is this called so I can look up Vue's documentation?

Comment: you need to `v-bind` the value, I'd used the shorthand above, i.e. `:value=` but could of written: `v-bind:value="{ ...` doing so will then get everything working as you'll pass an object, not a string

Comment: I've made a JSFiddle with your suggestion: https://jsfiddle.net/qc7yqvvs/2/ The value is still looking weird.

Comment: sorry - what looks weird about it? Do you mean the `NaN` for total before you select anything? If so check my answer as that has a check within the computed property that sorts that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you inspect the option element the value attribute will be `value="[object Object]"`. Also, I said screw it and used JQuery along with Vue: https://jsfiddle.net/qc7yqvvs/3/ What do you think of this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129115/discussion-between-danveira-and-guyc).